# Twilio <Dial> verb not working

Tags: php, twilio

I am trying to use Twilio to call a phone number. I was looking at their sample code here: http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial

When I copy and paste the following sample code it will not call the number:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
     <Dial>901-XXX-XXXX</Dial>
     <Say>Goodbye</Say>
</Response>
```

I put my phone # in and when I open up my web browser and go to the URL hosting this file, nothing happens. All it does it show me the XML tree. Am I missing something here? Isn't the script suppose to call my phone #?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio is not magic. Viewing an XML file in your browser does not make a call to Twilio (even if the XML file contains data that looks like Twilio commands). You need to make an API request to Twilio to make it do anything.

You should probably have a look at Twilio's "REST Quickstart" -- it'll lead you through the process of making an outbound call.

http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/rest

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions.

If you are trying to make a call from your Twilio number to other people's phone numbers, you need to make an API request to trigger the call. You can find PHP instructions here: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php#make-a-call. Once the other person answers the phone, Twilio will make an HTTP request to the URL you specify, asking for instructions about what to do with the call. At this point, you can specify that you'd like to connect the call to your own number.

If people are dialing in to your Twilio number, Twilio will make an HTTP request to your URL when the call comes in. The flow is the same as above.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Dial>+1901-XXX-XXXX</Dial>
<Say>Goodbye</Say>
</Response>

put +1 in font of area code.
```